# How can i set permision folder in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Folder in /srv/beta in Server Ubuntu 14.04 to upload source code. How can i set permision all user in dev-team alow all permision only this folder like vim, upload, .... 
Tks...

Comment: Tks very much brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CHMOD` command for changing the rights or permissions for the folder & `CHOWN` command for changing the ownership.

For changing the ownership you need to use `sudo` from root to yourself.

Here is the syntax

To change the ownership for the folder alone.

```
sudo chown <username>:<groupname> <foldername>
```

To change the ownership to the folder recursively for all the files and folders inside the folder.

```
sudo chown -R <username>:<groupname> <foldername>
```

Comment: `CHMOD` and `CHOWN` will not work as Unix is case sensitive, use `chmod` and `chown`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a group dev-team  `groupadd dev-team`.
Add users to that group `usermod -G <somegroup>,dev-team <username>`
Then set an owner to your folder `chown someuser:dev-team /srv/beta` and `chmod 660 /srv/beta` so anyone in group dev-team can read and write there.

Comment: But after that im switch `someuser` below i can not be used vim to create file in `/srv/beta` .
```sudo chown user1:devteam /srv/beta/
sudo chown user2:devteam /srv/beta/
sudo chown user3:devteam /srv/beta/
sudo chmod 660 /srv/beta/```
Only User 3 can used vim cli to write file in this folder.

Comment: Any user in group dev-team (you can add user to group with `usermod -G`)  is allowed to create files in that directory. No need to change owner of a directory.